# Printing out to a php page using AWS PHP SDK [S3]

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, request, xmlhttprequest

I am learning to use the PHP SDK by AWS.

What I want to achieve is, that when some user requests a .php page on my site.
`example.com/listbuckets.php`

That page should return the buckets associated with my IAM role.

Here's my code:

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest'
]);

//Listing all S3 Bucket
$buckets = $s3Client->listBuckets();
foreach ($buckets['Buckets'] as $bucket) {
    echo $bucket['Name'] . "\n";
}

?>
```

With that code, via CLI or terminal I can successfully see my S3 buckets. But when I request the page via browser, it shows 500 Internal Server Error.

What I am missing on here?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I tried passing my AWS Creds (key/secret) via:

```
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('key', 'secret');

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'eu-west-1',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
```

And I can't still resolve the php page if accesed via a web-browser, could this be an issue related to permissions/ownership? Even tho i can see my buckets if I execute via terminal
`php listbuckets.php`

EDIT2:
I passed a new parameter on

```
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'eu-west-1',
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'debug'       => true
]);
```

And now the page is responding with this chunk of text:

> -> Entering step init, name 'idempotency_auto_fill' --------------------------------------------------- command was set to array(3) { ["instance"]=> string(32) "044155c203a162626f000d004ff45d46" ["name"]=> string(11) "ListBuckets" ["params"]=> array(2) { ["@http"]=> array(1) { ["debug"]=> resource(4) of type (stream) } ["@context"]=> array(0) { } } } request was set to array(0) { } -> Entering step init, name 's3.ssec' ------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step init, name 's3.source_file' -------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step init, name 's3.save_as' ---------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step init, name 's3.location' ----------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step init, name 's3.auto_encode' -------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step init, name 's3.head_object' -------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step validate, name 'validation' -------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step validate, name 'input_validation_middleware' ------------------------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step build, name 'builder' -------------------------------------- request.instance was set to 00fq4442000004ffw2c46 request.method was set to GET request.headers was set to array(2) { ["X-Amz-Security-Token"]=> string(7) "[TOKEN]" ["Host"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" } } request.scheme was set to https request.path was set to / -> Entering step build, name 'ApiCallMonitoringMiddleware' ---------------------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step build, name '' ------------------------------- request.instance changed from e33e626cc to 00dw0sq03c45d46 request.headers.User-Agent was set to array(1) { [0]=> string(50) "aws-sdk-php/3.178.4 OS/Linux/4.19.0-16-cloud-amd64" } -> Entering step build, name 'endpoint_parameter' ------------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step build, name 'EndpointDiscoveryMiddleware' ---------------------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step build, name 's3.checksum' ------------------------------------------ no changes -> Entering step build, name 's3.content_type' ---------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step build, name 's3.endpoint_middleware' ----------------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step build, name 's3.bucket_endpoint_arn' ----------------------------------------------------- no changes -> Entering step sign, name 'StreamRequestPayloadMiddleware' ------------------------------------------------------------ no changes -> Entering step sign, name 'invocation-id' ------------------------------------------- request.instance changed from 000003a1626c9002f900025d46 to 0e55j00003a1626cy004ff4r3d46 request.headers.aws-sdk-invocation-id was set to array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "321593e23171d701cdwae9" } -> Entering step sign, name 'retry' ----------------------------------- request.instance changed from dw000qdqd04ff45d46 to 0400411626c4210004445d46 request.headers.aws-sdk-retry was set to array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "0/0" } -> Entering step sign, name 'signer' ------------------------------------ request.instance changed from 02z00004ss2004ff45d46 to 01626d000045d46 request.headers.x-amz-content-sha256 was set to array(1) { [0]=> string(64) "ec44298f9b934ca491b7855" } request.headers.X-Amz-Date was set to array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "25T142413Z" } request.headers.Authorization was set to array(1) { [0]=> string(211) "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=[KEY]/20210415/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=[SIGNATURE] }

I edited some of the values, but from Amazon, what's this error related to ?
Seems like a signature error

EDIT 3:
As I said, it seems like a signature error, I have compared the two chunks of code, one from the browser and the other from the terminal and the browser-petition just stops at.
`Entering step sign, name 'signer'`

**How could I sign (via browser) the same way I sign when I use my terminal from the ec2 instance?**

EDIT 4:
I managed and searched a lot, and found that I should be working with Pre-Signed URLS.
With the following code, I can grant a user a 20 minute lifespan link which will redirect him and show him all the available buckets.

```
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
]);

$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('ListBuckets', [
    'Bucket' => '*'
    
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url
$presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();
echo($presignedUrl);
```

EDIT 5:
If someone would like to print the result of the url generated by the AWS PHP SDK, use this php code

```
$result = file_get_contents($presignedUrl);
echo($result);
```

Finally, I got that, so I am gonna post the answer!

Comment: Is the 500 status returned by your server or AWS? If it's y our server then you should see the errors log file for details.

Comment: @Linek I edited with the response from AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the whole point was valid but I was executing it wrong, I recommend to anybody who's learning the AWS PHP SDK this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html) so he/she can understand better the concept of making presigned-urls from a browser/client.

---

Let's break down the question,
The scenario was, when somebody requested my listbuckets.php page, that page should print out all my S3 buckets. Ok.

Needed things:
1- AWS Account
2- EC2 Instance
3- S3 Buckets
4- Acces to EC2 via SSH
5- Composer on the EC2
6- AWS PHP SDK Installed on the root of your web-project.

When you have all those things, if you want to make an anonymous request from any user valid to AWS resources you should be working with **presigned-urls**.

Go to your `listbuckets.php`.

Code:

```
//Key and Secret are variables that you get from your IAM Acces Management
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('KEY','SECRET');

//Create an S3 Client to communicate with AWS.
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
]);

//Here we specify the command that we want to execute on our AWS resource.
//ListBuckets, Put object... 
//We tell with * to List **all** the buckets
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('ListBuckets', [
    'Bucket' => '*'
    
]);

//We make the request, including the command we want to execute and the lifespan //of the url. It will be available only 20min, 10min... Whatever you want.
$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url, with this URL can make the request to AWS and it will be valid, we will be requesting AWS to LIST ALL my S3 buckets.
$presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();
echo($presignedUrl . "<br>");
echo "<br>";


//What we are going to get, is an XML file, from that file we want (in my case) //the name only so...
$xml = simplexml_load_file($presignedUrl);
//echo $xml->Buckets->Bucket->Name; 
foreach ($xml->Buckets->Bucket as $namee)
{

    echo $namee->Name . "\n";
}
```

WIth this code, everytime someone asks the listbucket.php, in the backend, it will generate a valid request to aws, and print out the name of the response from that request.

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Place the code inside a try/catch block. Print the error message inside of the catch.

Did you already do a composer install?

All output of errors active in PHP?

Comment: I did a composer install using the following command.                                                        composer require aws/aws-sdk-php